# Windows won't accept new default program

Tags: windows, file-association

I am trying to set [MarkdownPad2](http://markdownpad.com/) as my default program for opening `.md` files on my Windows 7 PC. I installed MarkdownPad2 via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). If I open MarkdownPad2 and then use the File -> Open menu I can successfully open my file. However, if I right click the file on my desktop and go to Open With -> Choose Default Program, then click Browse, then navigate to  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MarkdownPad 2\MarkdownPad2.exe` and click Open, the program doesn't appear in the list of programs to open it with, even when I expand "Other Programs".

I also tried the same process through `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations` but had the same issue. The current default program is Microsoft's WebMatrix. How do I configure MarkdownPad2 as my default program for opening `.md` files?

---

Update: I uninstalled MarkdownPad2 and reinstalled directly from their website (without using Chocolatey) and still have the same issue. I think that eliminates Chocolatey as the source of the problem.

Comment: Windows 7 or Windows 8?

Comment: @LittleHelper It's in the first sentence of my question. Windows 7.